# Running Celery as a Daemon while using VirtualEnv

Tags: python, daemon, virtualenv

I've setup and tested celery on my amazon linux server, using mysql as the messaging backend and it works fine when running the program directly. My python project and celery install are located in a virtualenv. However if I attempt to daemonize celery by using the script [here](https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryd), the program refuses to run in the background.

I'm passing the virtualenv installed location of celery to the daemon in the config file using CELERYD="/opt/apps/myenv/[path to celeryd]" which equates to using the flag --cmd when starting celeryd.

The script always stops after starting worker node 1 and waits, as if I'm running the program directly and not daemonizing it. Celery is active at this point but stops after I close the terminal window or press ctrl-c.

I've tried running it without the --cmd, and it seems to run in the background, but the workers won't start, and calling stop returns an 'unknown instance'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.